# Program goes in an infinite loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This program goes in an infinite loop in while cycle. Please, can someone tell me why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class program {
    public static void main(String[] pars) {
        System.out.println("Insert something.");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        while(read.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(read.next());
        }
        System.out.println("End of program");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Ctrl+D` ends the stream...

Comment: there always is "next" until you end the stream ans mentioned above.

Comment: you need to create a end program keyword, then you end program System.Exit(0) when the user enter that

Comment: If you redirect stdin to read from a file, the loop should end as expected.

Comment: @IsabelHM: well `System.exit` exits the entire program whereas a `break` stops the loop, perhaps the program should do other things with the input after parsing (for instance calculate a result).

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, I agree. It's just an example of adding some sort of action to terminate the loop. The implementation depends on the consequent workflow so it's up to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the Javadoc of [`Scanner#hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()):

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Hence the `while` loop will always be executed in your case, each time waiting for input from the user. Since the `Scanner` is linked to `System.in`, the input stream will always block until the user inputs a string and `hasNext()` will always return true, unless the user signals the end of file (e.g. through the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> combination on Windows). `Scanner#hasNext()` is more convenient when reading from files where the input size is known and the end of the file marks the end of the stream.

One way to end the loop here is to add a condition on the input:

```
while (read.hasNext()) {
    s = read.next();
    if(s.equals("quit")) {
       break;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**P.S.**: It is more conventional to name classes starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Did +1, but perhaps you should mention that `hasNext()` keeps blocking until the stream ends.

Comment: @CommuSoft Updated with more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
while(read.hasNext()) {
```

If you use `System.in` as a stream provided by the user, it will - if no such input is available - as @manouti says, block and wait for input. But even if you provide input, it will keep waiting. The system has no means to detect whether the user wants to provide additional input in the future.

It will only *stop*, if the `Stream` ends. This can be under two conditions:

- The end of the file (in case of I/O redirection like `java -jar program.jar < input.dat`; or
- The user marks the end of a stream, in most shells with Ctrl+D. This marks the *end-of-stream*.

An alternative is to provide some kind of *stop directive*. Something like `"END"`. Thus:

```
while(read.hasNext()) {
    String nx = read.next();
    if(nx.equals("END")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(nx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove while loop

```
public static void main(String[] pars) {
System.out.println("Insert something.");
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";

        System.out.println(read.next());

    System.out.println("End of program");
}
```

Or if u want display certain no.of string then mention condition properly.

```
public static void main(String[] pars) {
System.out.println("Insert something.");
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = "";
    int i=0;
    while(i<5) {
        System.out.println(read.next());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("End of program");
}
```